# How to check if directory exists outside of workspace from a jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Given I have a directory path, how do I check if this directory exists outside of the workspace from a jenkins pipeline script.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tried a few things and turned out the answer was already in front of me.
***fileExists*** can check for directories as well. Here's how I got around the problem.
In this example, I am creating a directory on *Windows* if it doesn't exist.

**Step 1**: ***dir*** into the directory

```
dir("C:/_Tests")
```

**Step 2**: Now, use fileExists without any file name.

```
if(!fileExists("/"))
{
  bat "mkdir \"C:/_Tests\""
}
```

Comment: The dir function will create the directory for you automatically once you try to do something in it, so the `fileExists` can be skipped.

Answer (score 22):

im not sure that that was your question but fileExists() works for directories as well

Comment: Actually this should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 20):

**`fileExists(target_dir)`** in pipeline checks the given file in workspace, it is not permitted to access the outside.

to do this, the **`sh`** or **`bat`** in pipeline can help verify if the target directory exists by calling shell command.

```
res = sh(script: "test -d ${target_dir} && echo '1' || echo '0' ", returnStdout: true).trim()
if(res=='1'){
    echo 'yes'
} else {
    echo 'no'
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that looks like too much work if I have to check for multiple directories. In my case, I had to check for 10.

Comment: It can be written as a method. So it can be called multiple times

Comment: I would do `sh(script: "test -d ${target_dir}", returnStatus: true) == 0` no need for echo and string matching.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone interested a bit more universal (windows, mac, linux and shared library...):

```
def listDirectories(String Directory, String Pattern) {
  def dlist = []
  new File(Directory).eachDir {dlist << it.name }
  dlist.sort()
  dlist = dlist.findAll { it.contains Pattern }

  return dlist
}
```

usage (for this):

```
if (listDirectories(Directory: "C:/", Pattern: "Windows").size() == 1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

None from suggestions above worked for me...

This is 100% working code:

```
                        efs_path = '~/efs-mount-point'
                        stdout = sh( script: '''#!/bin/bash
                        set -ex
                        if [ -d ''' + efs_path + ''' ]; then
                            echo "true"
                        else
                            echo "false"
                        fi
                        ''', returnStdout: true)

                        echo stdout

                        if (stdout.contains('false')) {
                            error('No such directory: ' + efs_path)
                        }
```